# Godaddy cname "@" not working (instructions from Heroku)

Tags: domain, cname-record

I created a little app on Heroku, and am trying to follow their directions for setting up a custom domain on Godaddy. I've created a CNAME for www, but I can't create one for @ (or mydomain.com. per their instructions.

I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR - DNS Rules Violation, A record of a different type exists for this hostname, CNAME 
cannot be created for @
```

No matter which combination of dots and @'s I use. Anyone know how to add that cname with just the root domain and not the www?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've set up a domain with godaddy using heroku so see if this helps.

First you set up 3 A records with the hostname @ to point to the heroku ips: 75.101.163.44, 75.101.145.87, and 174.129.212.2 (check their docs to make sure they are the same when you do this).

Then you add just one CNAME record if you want www and have it point to @.

If you use the total DNS control feature your screen will end up looking something like this:

[image]

You also need to use the heroku addon for DNS and configure it:

```
heroku addons:add custom_domains:basic
heroku domains:add yourdomainname.com
heroku domains:add www.yourdomainname.com
```

Doing the above should get you set up with their free basic DNS service.

Comment: @djangofan: No, Heroku don't use mongrel.  Also, the relationship between the numbers of frontend webservers and app servers is tenuous at best.

Comment: These settings are old and incorrect. You can no longer use these 3 IP addresses with Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

You can't -- a CNAME can't be used if a resource record has any other records on it (which a root name has -- NS records and an SOA, at a minimum).  What you'll have to do is put an A record on the name, pointing to the IP address of the name that heroku suggest you put the CNAME on.

Comment: Bummer...by the way, you happen to know of any videos out there that explain DNS, CNAMEs and such out there?

Comment: What is this obsession with learning from videos?  They're hard to make right, hard to watch, hard to follow along... get a good book, like the O'Reilly BIND book, or RFC1034/RFC1035.